# Описка или опечатка? (Применительно к публикациям в интернете)

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография, выбор-слов

Говоря о материалах, помещенных в интернете, какое слово следует употреблять:  *описка* или *опечатка*? Имеет ли значение вид публикации (форум, блог, информационный сайт и т. д.)?

Дополнение. Интересно, как это называлось, когда автор использовал пишущую машинку?

Comment: Опи́ска – ошибка, обычно неумышленная, при написании послания или документа. В психологическом плане рассматривается как разновидность парапраксиса. Если ошибка не выявлена при рецензировании и/или корректурах, она называется опечатка.

Comment: @shampar Проблема в том, что о публикациях в интернете мы не знаем,  прошли они рецензирование и/или корректуру или вышли прямо "из-под пера автора". Пожалуй, только о форумах можно  сказать, что это второе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это явно техническая ошибка, то мой выбор в пользу "опечатки" (второе больше подходит к рукописным текстам), более формально (и менее дипломатично - с намёком на небрежность) это "*ошибка набора текста*". Так её и в книгах по работе с текстом именуют, напр. https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=W4Pd2M0Dm7wC&hl=ru&pg=PA296&img=1&zoom=3&ots=BgMol6sYlz&sig=ACfU3U20cWrzBGRtEtIiuKaG4tNB-X7vTg&w=1280

Comment: То есть по-Вашему, в эпоху компьютеров слово "описка" неверно/неуместно? Интересно, как это называлось, когда автор  использовал пишущую машинку?

Comment: "Опечаткой" точно называлось - технически на машинке "печатают" (даже писатели - если сами) или "отпечатывают (текст)", хоть она и "пишущая" чаще всего. На принтерах "**рас**печатывают". "Описка" после школы я редко слышал по какому-либо поводу.

Comment: Пример из обл. криминалистики: http://lib.sale/uchebnik-kriminalistika/mashinopisnyiy-tekst-48133.html
_обнаружена записка, **отпечатанная** на пишущей машинке... **Машинописный** текст **отпечатан** при помощи копировальной ленты черного цвета._ Писатель пишет, (технически) **печатая** на машинке.

Comment: Это понятно, но вот @shampar ставит во главу угла не способ нанесения текста на бумагу, а прохождение рецензирования/корректуры. Что говорил писателю редактор/корректор: "у вас описка" или "у вас опечатка"? Что он говорит теперь, читая полученный текстовый файл?

Comment: Пример (пока с сайта любительской прозы): https://www.proza.ru/2016/09/09/1127 _Корректор... исправит все ошибки, как орфографические, так и пунктуационные, а также **авторские опечатки**._

Comment: О работе корректора: https://iklife.ru/internet-professii/professiya-korrektor-tekstov.html 1) вычитывает текст, правит орфографические, пунктуационные ошибки и опечатки